# Prove for all subsets $_1$ and $_2$ of B, if $^{−1}(_1) = ^{−1}(_2)$, then $_1 = _2$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let
$f : A \rightarrow B$ be an onto function.
Prove for all subsets $_1$ and $_2$ of $B$, if $^{−1}(_1) = ^{−1}(_2)$, then $_1 = _2$.

I have attempted this question but I am a bit confused. I essentially stated that

since we are assuming f is onto, and $^{−1}(_1) = ^{−1}(_2)$, that $(a)=_1$ and $(a)=_2$ and so $f(a)=f(a)$, therefore $_1=_2$.

However since a is mapped to 2 values then f is not a well defined function so this obviously won't work, and I have hit a sticking point. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proving equality of sets is normally done by proving they are subsets of each other.

Let $x\in B_1$. Then $f^{-1}(x)\in f^{-1}(B_1)=f^{-1}(B_2)$.
Hence $x\in f(f^{-1}(B_2))=B_2$ since $f$ is onto.
We conclude that $B_1\subseteq B_2$.
The reverse inclusion is done by similar way.

Comment: D'Oh! Of course, I'm so used to dealing with straight variables in function problems like this and not sets I totally forgot about that. Thanks!